# Is there a way to get unique values multiple times from class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, oop

So, I am working on personal project which generates random data depending on locale, so, I have a below code

```
class _DataProto (DataProvider): # DataProto.py
    value_dict = {}
    data_obj = {'data':[]}
    def get_name(self):
        value_dict['name'] = self.name() # Method provided by DataProvider

    def get_dob(self):
        value_dict['dob'] = self.dob() # Method provided by DataProvider

    def get_email(self):
        value_dict['email'] = self.email()  # SAME
  
    def set_data(self):
        # that calls all the method above
        return self.value_dict
    
    def get_multiple_data(self,quantity):
        for _ in range(quantity):
            self.data_obj['data'].append(self.set_data())
        return data_obj  # this returns multiple values but with same data in them,
                         # I have also tried with temp.append(self.value_dict) calling self.set_data() first
    
    def get_multiple_data2 (self,quantity):
        temp = []
        for _ in range(quantity):
            temp.append(self.set_data())
        return temp  # this also does same thing as above I have also tried with temp.append(self.value_dict)
```

---

```
class Data1(_DataProto, DataProvider1): # Data1.py
      # DataProvier1 provides local based data
      pass
```

---

```
# main.py

gh = Data1()
# gh.get_name(), gh.get_dob() and all works as expected
gh.get_multiple_data2(2) # returns {"data":[{valueA}, {same value as valueA}]}

for _ in range(2):
    print(gh.set_data) # return different value everytime
```

I would like to implement method within `_DataProto` that allows me to get data_obj with multiple values appended to it that are unique.

`set_data` method alwasy return unique value.

Comment: You are using the wrong comment identifiers... python uses # for comments not //

Comment: Make a script that demonstrates the problem and cut and paste exactly into this question.

Comment: It would appear that calls to `self.set_data()` will always return the same value, so the list in `self.data_obj['data']` will just have that many copies of that same value - why would you expect them to be different?

Comment: "`gh.get_name()`, `gh.get_dob()` and all works as expected", is this true? The assignment of both methods lacks `self`.

Comment: Please show the expected/desired results, the actual results, and explain how the latter fails to meet the former. Consult the [help] articles for more guidelines, especially "[ask]" and providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `self.email()` and `self.dob()` and `self.name()` methods generate unique data every time they are called then you can change the `set_data` method to call the methods above it every time it is called.

You will also want to copy the dictionary contents using `deepcopy` as the return value from `set_data` so that each iteration doesn't update the same dictionary.

```
from copy import deepcopy

class _DataProto (DataProvider):
    value_dict = {}

    def get_name(self):
        value_dict['name'] = self.name()

    def get_dob(self):
        value_dict['dob'] = self.dob()

    def get_email(self):
        value_dict['email'] = self.email()
  
    def set_data(self):
        self.get_email()
        self.get_dob()
        self.get_name()
        return deepcopy(self.value_dict)
    
    def get_multiple_data(self, quantity):
        data_obj = {'data': []}
        for _ in range(quantity):
            data_obj['data'].append(self.set_data())
        return data_obj
```

You could also simplify your code by simply returning a new dictionary each time `set_data` is called.

For example:

```
class _DataProto (DataProvider):

    def set_data(self):
        return {
            'name': get_name(),
            'email': get_email(),
            'dob': get_dob()
        }
    
    def get_multiple_data(self, quantity):
        data_obj = {'data': []}
        for _ in range(quantity):
            data_obj['data'].append(self.set_data())
        return data_obj
```